# Prob. 2, Chap. 4 in Baby Rudin: What properties to look for in a function so that $f(\overline{E})$ is a proper subset of $\overline{f(E)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Here is Prob. 2, Chap. 4 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> If $f$ is a continuous mapping of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$, prove that $$ f(\overline{E}) \subset \overline{f(E)}$$ for every set $E \subset X$. ($\overline{E}$ denotes the closure of $E$.) Show, by an example, that $f(\overline{E})$ can be a proper subset of $\overline{f(E)}$.

I think I can prove the main result. It is in Munkres' *Topology*, 2nd edition, where it has been proved for a general topological space. Am I right?

But what property (or properties) should I look for a function $f$ which may provide the desired counter-example?

Let $y$ be a point of $\overline{f(E)} - f(\overline{E})$. Then as $y \in \overline{f(E)}$, so for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a point $q_\varepsilon \in f(E)$ such that $$d_Y \left( y, q_\varepsilon \right) < \varepsilon.$$ 
But as $y \not\in f(\overline{E})$, so there is no point $x \in \overline{E}$ for which $y = f(x)$. What next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider cases where $E$ is closed but $f(E)$ isn't (hence $E$ should also be noncompact).  For example, mapping $\mathbb R$ continuously onto a proper open interval works, if $X=Y=\mathbb R$.

Comment: how about the function $f \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$ f(x) = \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ has the usual metric, and the set $E = [0, +\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, that works.  With the same function you could take $E=\mathbb R$, or any other closed unbounded set.

Answer (score 0):

For any spaces $A, B$ the topological def'n of continuity of $f:A\to B$ is that $f^{-1}T$ is open in $A$ whenever $T$ is open in $B.$ This is equivalent to: $$\forall E\subset A\;
(\; f(Cl_A(E))\subset Cl_B(f(E))\;).$$  A function $f:A\to B$ such that $f(E)$ is closed in $B$ whenever $E$ is closed in $A$ is commonly  called a closed mapping. Examples of continuous functions that are not closed mappings are abundant.

For example with $A=\mathbb R^2$ and $B=\mathbb R$ the function $f((x,y))=x$ is continuous. Let $E=\{(x,1/x): 1\geq x>0\}$. Then $E$ is closed in $A$ but $f(E)= (0,1]$ is not closed in $B.$